# Mix Firebase Web SDK with React Native Firebase for Auth, Analytics & Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I have 1) Firebase Web SDK and 2) React Native Firebase working independently in my current Expo project. But I have to mix both because:

- React Native Firebase does not support web (official answer: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/4417#discussioncomment-105475)
- Firebase Web SDK does not support Analytics, nor Dynamic Links. And I need both.

I found a code template where the maintainer of React Native Firebase applies shims to get React Native for Web working, while still using React Native Firebase for iOS and Android
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-authentication-example

I thought I had it working (with support by ChatGPT) but I just realized that I was merely using the Web SDK for Web and native with those shims:

```
import firebase, {persistence} from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

import initializeApp from "./firebase-init";
initializeApp();

const auth = firebase.auth;

export default auth;
```

Question:
I replicated all shims + added a new one for Dynamic Links as seen here in the template: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-authentication-example/tree/main/template/src/shims

What am I missing to solve this problem?

Much thanks in advance!!